# Make 2 divs fill page responsive to browser with a fixed footer and header

Tags: css, html

I have a fixed header and footer of 50px and I would like an upper and lower div to fill the remainder of the page without overlap. Here is my

```
section{
width:100%;
text-align: center;
}

section .lower, section .upper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  position:absolute;
  padding: 5px 0;
  z-index: 901;
  text-align: center;
  display:block;
  clear: both;
}

section .upper{
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  opacity:.2;
}

section .lower{
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;

  background-color: #afa;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Comment: do you have a fiddle or codepen to show us the whole picture ? What about the scrolling ?

Comment: I'm using a onepage plugin so each section is one full page. When I scroll it brings me to the next page. 

http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

Comment: is it something of that kind http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vlmuH ? without your code ....

Comment: exactly what I am looking for, is there any way to do it without the flex property?

Comment: yes there is, http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dpAer if header and footers have known height.

Answer (score 0):

there's these 2 possibilities:

1. the use of `display:flex;` **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vlmuH/)**
2. the use of box-model with `box-sizing:border-box`,`padding`, `absolute`, `relative`  and `height`. **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dpAer)** . `header` and `footer` must have a known `height`. (px,em,vh,..)